# car stereo connectors

Tags: honda, audio, crv

I just bought a new stereo for my Honda CRV and now I would like to buy a connector to avoid rewiring. Unfortunately neither of the two plugs are standard connectors. Does anyone know what these connectors are called? I think the blue one is just the Honda proprietary connector... What is the second one? Anyone knows where i can buy a lead that goes from the blue connector to the socket of the black one?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I won't put this as an answer, because I do not know where you reside ... ***BUT*** if you have a Best Buy anywhere near you, go to their car audio shop and ask them for a wiring adapter. Tell them what year/make/model of car you have and show them the pictures you showed us here. They can get you the right adapter for your needs. If you don't have a Best Buy, any aftermarket audio shop will have the connectors ... you just have to show them what you need.

Comment: The black connector is one that came with the new stereo? What is on the other end of the wires? Typically aftermarket stereos will have a plug like that which plugs into the head unit itself, and the wires hang free which you must connect to the car. The best way to do that is to buy an adapter kit for your car, and you make a harness adapter with the kit and the pigtail for the new stereo, then just plug everything in and mount the stereo.

Comment: As dobey suggested, there is no already made cable on the market. The wires just hang free on the other side of the cable and i will make a harness adapter myself... Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Know this is an old post an will have been solved.

It is quite simple
Buy a Honda to ISO adaptor lead, such as P/No CT20HD02
This will then convert the Honda lead to ISO power and speaker sockets.
Plug ISO connectors from stereo into the sockets - done.

If the supplier has supplied with bare ends best to obtain the ISO sockets and crimp onto the bare ends. These ones will do:
http://connects2.co.uk/Product/ProductItem/361320

Once the socket are on the wires it is a straight froward "plug and play" job

Comment: I ended up soldering the 2 cable wires together...